# After suspend mode (lid close/open) screen remains black

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, suspend, laptop, power-management

I have installed `Ubuntu Gnome` on my `Dell XPS15 9550`. I have issues with the suspend mode. Whenever I close the lid, and then open it again (after a few minutes, to ensure the notebook went into suspend mode), the notebook turns back on, but the screen stays black! Only solution is always to hard reset the notebook.

I recently installed the `4.4.8 kernel`, but it didn't changed anything.

Specifications:

- CPU: Intel 6700HQ (skylake)
- 16GB RAM
- Intel integrated graphics
- Nvidia 960M dedicated graphics card

EDIT: I tried to login after I opened the lid (because only the screen turns black, but the notebook still works). So I managed to log in, trough the black screen, and opened a terminal with the shortcut and typed reboot. Success! The notebook restarted. This leads to the conclusion that only the screen stays black, but the OS is operating normally after waking up.

Comment: This feels like a driver issue. What drivers are you using for your 960M?

Comment: First I was using the X.Org Server drivers. I then switched to the Nvidia binary drivers (361.42). Didn't helped. 
Also tried to switch to the Intel graphics card in the `Nvidia X Server Settings`